# pattern and image both using css

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have a situation where I have fill the body with a background image which is nothing but a pattern - so I would use

```
body
{
background-image:url('paper.gif');
background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
```

but now I also need one more image to set on top of this which will appear the horizontal and vertical center of screen, (this image ofcourse smaller and would only occupy the center).
Its like putting 2 images in BG smaller one over the another.  How could I do that?
And I have to do that in javascript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using pseudo elements.

[CSS desk demo](http://cssdesk.com/Lshbc)

```
body
{
   background:url(http://placehold.it/200x100) repeat;
}
body:after
{
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `css3` you can achieve something like this (two images), since your question is tagged with `HTML5`, so I think you can use this probably

```
body {
    background: url('paper.gif'), url('another.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat-y, no-repeat;
}
```

This is an example but not sure how you want to place both images.

Comment: is it one of those features from css3 which is supported by IE8? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately no, `IE-8` is not able to handle this.

Comment: Thanks Recovering - but I need it on IE8 as well.  Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either apply a `z-index:{NUMBER};` that is greater than the body's `z-index` (default `1`) if you don't mind the top of your background image being cut off (or you can just edit the image to have an empty bar at the top to account for your header).

Or, apply your background not to `body`, but to whatever your main content div underneath your header is.